Can I make rendering of BSplineCurves more accurate?
My gently curving BSplines are being rendered as straight lines that are long enough to look bad.  As an example, consider drawing a dartboard, with its twenty colored sectors.  The outer boundaries of those sectors are circular arcs.  To render each sector as a FilledCurve, its boundary segments must be either Lines, BezierCurves, or BSplineCurves --- arcs of Circles are not allowed.  Fortunately, if I set my SplineWeights properly, a BSplineCurve can exactly trace out a circular arc.  Here is code that draws a simple dartboard at ImageSize = 400:
dartSector = 
  FilledCurve[{BSplineCurve[{
       {1, 0}, 
       {1, Tan[\[Pi]/20]}, 
       {Cos[\[Pi]/10], Sin[\[Pi]/10]}}, 
     SplineWeights -> {1, Cos[\[Pi]/20], 1}], 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}];

dartBoard = Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1],
   Table[Rotate[dartSector, k \[Pi]/20, {0, 0}], 
      {k, 1, 37, 4}],
   Red,
   Table[Rotate[dartSector, k \[Pi]/20, {0, 0}],
     {k, 3, 39, 4}],
   }, ImageSize -> 400]

The result looks good:

But if I reduce the ImageSize to 350, the outer boundaries of the sectors are rendered as straight lines, which are obviously wrong:

Is there some switch or parameter that I can set to make the rendering of such BSplineCurves more accurate?

If I reduce the ImageSize to 350 in the Graphics expression, it still looks fine. So, can you please provide the code that produced the "bad" output?

Also, did you try using Disk? You can use Disk to create just a slice between two angles. That would seem to me to be an easier way to create a dartboard. If you real image isn't a dartboard, then it would be helpful to see what you're really working with.

I can reproduce the figures on V14.1 Mac ARM.

In response to lericr's comments:  A dartboard was just a simple example.  My actual target is a complicated diagram of a tiling of the Poincare-disk model of the hyperbolic plane --- way too complicated to include as part of this question.  As for varying the ImageSize, I suggest using the mouse to grow and shrink your generated graphic and watching for when its outline becomes an icosagon.  The transition to an icosagon happens for me, using Wolfram 14.1 on a Windows 11 desktop, between ImageSize 400 and 350; your mileage may vary.

From this answer by @J.M. to an earlier question by the OP to this answer by @Mr.Wizard:
dartSector = FilledCurve[{
    BSplineCurve[{{1, 0}, {1, Tan[\[Pi]/20]}, {Cos[\[Pi]/10], 
       Sin[\[Pi]/10]}}, SplineWeights -> {1, Cos[\[Pi]/20], 1}]
    , Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}];

dartBoard = 
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
   Table[Rotate[dartSector, k \[Pi]/20, {0, 0}], {k, 1, 37, 4}], Red, 
   Table[Rotate[dartSector, k \[Pi]/20, {0, 0}], {k, 3, 39, 4}]}
  , ImageSize -> 400,
  BaseStyle ->
   {FilledCurveBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 12}}}]


The integer 12 may be replaced by any sufficiently large integer.
On my machine with the original code without the option, the automatic number of sample points seems to grow as the length of the arc grows. At the OP's initial ImageSize -> 400, I see two segments, from endpoint to midpoint to other endpoint. If I increase the size of the figure to around 700, I get three.

Note: Many, probably alll, of these automatically generated primitives have options that control the generation of the primitive. Names["*BoxOptions"] lists them and many other object-box-options, not all of them graphics primitives.  Some of the usages may be found searching this site. Some are probably unknown (outside of WRI).

My hearty thanks to "Michael E2" for pointing me at two earlier appearances of the answer --- one of which, I am embarrassed to see, answered my own earlier question!  I apologize for the repetition.

@LyleRamshaw Yeah, but who remembers any details from the Pandemic? :)
